# MSI behaving stangely

Tags: c++, windows-installer

I have a few C++ DLLs and a C# console application which uses those DLLs. I made an MSI intsaller to deploy them. But when I install the package using the MSI, on opening the console application, it is getting closed immediatley without doing any work. But if I copy all the DLLs and the exe to some other folder other than the installed older, the app is working fine.

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check the event log. It sometimes gives you good info on why apps fail to launch.

Comment: @djs Thanks for the reply. I tried to look into the event logs.. But there was no log recorded from my application

Comment: Pehaps you mixed up some debug vs. release DLLs. Check with the dependency walker, if the DLLs fit together.

Comment: also check permissions to run the EXE, usually you need to run it deferred with no impersonation, otherwise the UAC will prevent it from running.